# WebMethod not closing SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, database, webmethod

Another problem with web service. This time Im passing two strings using WebMethod and Im trying to save them to database. So far so good. Everything works fine.
But....
But when I close application and want to display data from that database/table error message keep saying database is still used by other application.
Here is my WebService code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string GetValues(string value, string value2)
        {
            try
            {
            string crime = value;
            string invest = value2;

            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection();
            cs.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" + "Trusted_Connection=True;" + "AttachDbFilename=C:\\Temp\\Dokumenty\\Uczelnia\\Application Development\\Coursework2\\Coursework2\\Try\\Menu\\Menu\\Users.mdf;";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblScene VALUES(@CrimeSceneID, @InvestigatorID, @DataArtefactID)", cs);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CrimeSceneID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = crime;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InvestigatorID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = invest;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataArtefactID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "hello";
            cs.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            da.Dispose();


                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // return the error message if the operation fails
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }
```

I was trying to close my cs connection, even tried to dispose DataAdapter - no luck. After trying to rebuild whole project twice I can finally access database and confirm that everything i was trying to save is there.
Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: I see some major issues here, if any of this code throws an exception when the connection is open it becomes a memory leak.  Use a `using` statement to initiate your connection or at least a try / catch block that includes a `finally` statement.  You also shouldn't return your error message, you should `throw ex;`

Comment: Did you try using a static connection?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetValues(string value, string value2)
    {
        try
        {
            string crime = value;
            string invest = value2;

            using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection())
            {
                cs.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" + "Trusted_Connection=True;" + "AttachDbFilename=C:\\Temp\\Dokumenty\\Uczelnia\\Application Development\\Coursework2\\Coursework2\\Try\\Menu\\Menu\\Users.mdf;";

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblScene VALUES(@CrimeSceneID, @InvestigatorID, @DataArtefactID)", cs);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CrimeSceneID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = crime;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InvestigatorID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = invest;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataArtefactID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "hello";
                    cs.Open();
                    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // return the error message if the operation fails
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope, no luck. I noticed that before there was a bit missing about database path. It is not that. I think code might be good. I think I might messed up something with database?

Comment: So none of this solutions solved my problem. Although my original code wasn't perfect but somehow values were recorded in database. Now when I using try/catch or "using" i keep getting error about cannot login as a user: "dektop-PC\Administrator" (my machine name/administrator).

Can someone understand that? :)

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to utilize USING. Then your connection will automatically get disposed of when end of USING has been reached.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetValues(string value, string value2)
{
    try
        {
            string crime = value;
                string invest = value2;

                using(SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" + "Trusted_Connection=True;"))
        {

                    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {

                        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblScene VALUES(@CrimeSceneID, @InvestigatorID, @DataArtefactID)", cs);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CrimeSceneID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = crime;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InvestigatorID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = invest;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataArtefactID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "hello";
                        cs.Open();
                        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
        }

                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // return the error message if the operation fails
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }
}
```

Comment: Im getting message:
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'desktop-PC\administrator'.
Database is created within main Project by Add\NewItem\Service-Based Database.

Comment: I think I need to create a user to be able to login? When I removed "Trusted_Connection=True;" it says now: Login failed for user"".
Any help here? Im not very good with databases. Is there any custom user to login?